Pentaho Server: Shell Script with Python Code ModuleNotFoundError
I ran the job associated in my Pentaho data integration client in Pentaho server and when I saw the log results of the job it says that the python library 'Pandas' doesn't exist on the server where the Pentaho server runs...
Hello! I have a Pentaho PDI project uploaded in a Pentaho Server Suite so I can Schedule and run all of my PDI projects...
Right now I have a project in PDI in which flow starts running a Shell object configured with a Python Script where inside this script have the Pandas library and when I run the job on the Pentaho Server Suite gives me the following log:
Job - Start of job execution
Job - Starting entry Shell 3
Shell 3 - Running on platform : Linux

Shell 3 - Executing command : /home/pentaho/pentaho-server/tomcat/temp/kettle_87037a5e-0e27-11ef-9789-f761d4300bd8shell
Job - Starting entry Shell
Shell - Running on platform : Linux
Shell - Executing command : /home/pentaho/pentaho-server/tomcat/temp/kettle_87857b9f-0e27-11ef-9789-f761d4300bd8shell
Shell - ERROR (version 9.4.0.0-343, build 0.0 from 2022-11-08 07.50.27 by buildguy) : (stderr) Traceback (most recent call last):
Shell - ERROR (version 9.4.0.0-343, build 0.0 from 2022-11-08 07.50.27 by buildguy) : (stderr)   File "/home/pentaho/convertir_excel_a_csv.py", line 1, in \<module\>
Shell - ERROR (version 9.4.0.0-343, build 0.0 from 2022-11-08 07.50.27 by buildguy) : (stderr)     import pandas as pd
Shell - ERROR (version 9.4.0.0-343, build 0.0 from 2022-11-08 07.50.27 by buildguy) : (stderr) ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
Job - Finished job entry Shell result= false

This is strange because in PDI when I run locally this project doesn't give me the error but in Pentaho Server it does...
I tried creating a virtual environment where I have the libraries installed but Pentaho Server didn't run the virtual environment either...
I try to create a bash file where I have the Python script or the call of the virtual environment and I don't have success either...
I have installed the pandas library on the server and when I run it on the console level the scripts run without a problem.
